# Azure DevOps Release - how to substitute variables in a helm chart values.yaml file?

Tags: azure-devops, kubernetes-helm

I have searched and tried myself but can't get this to work. It seems that in an Azure DevOps Release Pipeline, I can only substitute variables from my `Variable Group` in a JSON or XML file.

I would think that my use-case is fairly common, to substitute variables defined in values.yaml in a helm chart (e.g. defined as #{LoadBalancerIP}) with variables defined in Azure DevOps.

Does anyone know how I would be able to achieve this? Or is variable substitution in a helm chart values file a wrong approach and that is why it is not supported?

Thank you for your help, it is much appreciated!

(Apologies if I have missed some important information or something, as this is my first question on stackoverflow)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the most elegant solution, but you could use the Replace Token task to make the variable substitutions as part of your pipeline.
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens

Comment: Thank you, my understanding was that this task only works for `xml` and `JSON` files but I am glad to know it works for `yaml` files as well. Thanks again!

Comment: It can actually be used for any text file.  Glad to have helped you!